# Why execute query with 2 insert cannot be executed?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am newbie in MySQL 8 and try to run this **query in one time at dBeaver**

```
INSERT INTO `m_permission` 
(`grouping`, `code`, `entity_name`, `action_name`, `can_maker_checker`) 
VALUES
('accounting', 'CREATE_GLACCOUNT', 'GLACCOUNT', 'CREATE', 1),
('accounting', 'UPDATE_GLACCOUNT', 'GLACCOUNT', 'UPDATE', 1),
('accounting', 'DELETE_GLACCOUNT', 'GLACCOUNT', 'DELETE', 1),
('accounting', 'CREATE_GLCLOSURE', 'GLCLOSURE', 'CREATE', 1),
('accounting', 'UPDATE_GLCLOSURE', 'GLCLOSURE', 'UPDATE', 1),
('accounting', 'DELETE_GLCLOSURE', 'GLCLOSURE', 'DELETE', 1),
('accounting', 'CREATE_JOURNALENTRY', 'JOURNALENTRY', 'CREATE', 1),
('accounting', 'REVERSE_JOURNALENTRY', 'JOURNALENTRY', 'REVERSE', 1);


INSERT INTO `m_role` 
(`id`, `name`, `description`)
VALUES
(1,'Super user','This role provides all application permissions.');
```

But, I'm stuck in this error

Query execution failed

```
Reason:
SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `m_role` 
(`id`, `name`, `description`)
VALUES
(1,'Super user','This' at line 15
```

So, what should I do to fix this error? Thank you

Comment: I'm no expert in MySQL, but standard debugging questions apply: do the insert statements work when you run them independently?

Comment: I cannot see a problem with the code, how/where are you executing it?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Is this the whole code? What happens if you remove single values and try to run these queries?

Comment: You might get this error if you had missed the terminator after the first insert but that is not the case with the published code - did you unconsciously fix this when publishing?

Comment: Maybe your description field has a length lower than string This role provides all application permissions.

Comment: @Joe Taras if the data is to long for the column then you would get ERROR 1406 (22001): Data too long for column 'description' at row ..

Comment: The query will be executed if I run one by one every Insert statement. But I want to execute 2 Insert statements at one time. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: @Fanny Agustiawan  there's nothing to help you with the code as published works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Show me the structure of database I think there is some issue with your database columns!!

Comment: This should be added as a comment and not an answer.

Comment: due to low reputation, I cannot add comments. That's why I add this in answer!!